Secure specific endpoints on wildfly with Keycloak
We're looking into securing only specific JaxRS endpoints of our Wildfly 26 Application with an OIDC Provider. However, we also have a separate section of the App which authenticates users via FORM. I couldn't find any guide for that and I couldn't figure it out with the Wildfly Elytron documentation.
I tried adding a separate authentication realm to the Wildfly standalone.xml:
<security-domain         name="oidc-domain"
                 default-realm="OidcRealm"
                 permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
    <realm name="OidcRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
</security-domain>

<token-realm name="OidcRealm">
    <jwt issuer="keycloak auth realm"
         audience="keycloak client name"
         public-key="...">
    </jwt>
</token-realm>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron-oidc-client:1.0">
    <secure-deployment name="mywar.war">
        <provider-url>keycloak realm url</provider-url>
        <client-id>keycloak client id</client-id>
        <credential name="secret" secret="keycloak client secret"/>
    </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>

<server name="default-server">
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/rest/onlineportal" handler="welcome-content">
                <filter-ref name="oidc-security"/>
            </location>
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content">
                <filter-ref name="form-security"/>
            </location>
        </host>
...
</server>

    <filters>
        <filter name="oidc-security"
                module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"
                class-name="org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.ElytronRunAsHandler">
            <param name="security-domain" value="oidc-domain"/>
        </filter>
        <filter name="form-security"
                module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"
                class-name="org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.ElytronRunAsHandler">
            <param name="security-domain" value="form-domain"/>
        </filter>
    </filters>

